# Tests stopped working in AndroidStrudio with ClassNotFound exception

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, classnotfoundexception

I am writing `GeodeticCalculator` class for Android and would like to test it. 
The tests should run on big machine, not on Android, since the purpose is to test geometry calculations.

Test class is located under `src/test/...` not under `src/androidTest/...`

AndroidStudio recognizes tests in the class, providing green "run" icons against each testing method.

Unfortunately, when they ran, the report is

```
Class not found: "...examplepath.GeodeticCalculatorTest"Empty test suite.
```

This started to happen suddenly, while "5 minutes ago" it was working. 
I have a lot of tests in the app, which were working previously. Now all of them are "not found".

Comment: Might be Android Studio bug. What happens if you run it second time?

Comment: Have you handled it? I've got the same problem

Comment: Don't know if it help but after 4 hours I tried on emulator and it works correctly